# SQL Server : select all if parameter is not null and one condition is false

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get data in below code, which has scenarios as below.

1. when @status = 0 and date is not null then get filtered data.
2. when @status = 1 and date is not null then select all data.
3. when @status = 1 and date is null then select all data.

   ```
   declare @status int = 0,
           @date datetime = '2018-12-01 09:48:34.343'

   select CreatedTime 
   from AspNetUsers 
   where @date is null 
      or (@status = 1 and CreatedTime > '2018-12-01 09:48:34.343')
   ```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Yes. Please include the expected results....

Comment: Is the cenario 2 and 3 the same? You could only check the status variable.
If you use 2 querys as your variable status doesnt belong in the table. 
You can use "IF"s statments to do that: IF(@status=1) Select * FROM AsNetUsers. 
IF(@status =0) SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers WHERE <your filter>.
Am I reading it right?

Comment: What about when `@status = 0 and date is null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic you describe is handled by:

```
where (@status = 0 and CreatedTime > @date) or
      (@status = 1)
```

It is unclear why you have two different variables for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @status INT = 0,
        @date DATETIME = '2018-12-01 09:48:34.343'


DECLARE @RQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @RQuery = ' WHERE 1 = 1 '

IF @status = 0 AND @date IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @RQuery =  @status + ' = 0 AND  CreatedTime ' + CAST(@date AS DATE)
END
ELSE IF @status = 1 AND @date IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @RQuery =  ''
END
ELSE IF @status = 1 AND @date IS  NULL
BEGIN
    SET @RQuery =  ''
END

DECLARE @RQueryFULL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @RQueryFULL = ''

SET @RQueryFULL = 'SELECT CreatedTime 
FROM AspNetUsers ' + @RQuery

EXEC @RQueryFULL
Try This
```